# Locators for elements with same attributes

Tags: selenium

I have hard time writing an xpath for elements that have same attributes. The absolute xpath doesn't work because the only distinguishing element div[#] keeps changing. Any advise will be greatly appreciated.
This is DOM for the 1st element

```
<div class="logoSelect' style=z-index: 1; top: 1613px; left: 292.75px; width: auto; display: block;">
 <ul>
  <li class=logoSelectOption id ="N" onmouseover="jQuery('#worktitle').activate(this);" 
   onmouseout="jQuery('#worktitle').deactivate();" 
   onmousedown="jQuery('#worktitle').selectItem(this);" 
   logo-colour="#FFF">No
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

This is DOM for the 2nd element:

```
<div class="logoSelect' style=style="z-index: 1; top: 1716px; left: 292.75px; width: auto; display:       
block;">
 <ul>
  <li class=logoSelectOption id ="N" onmouseover="jQuery('#agendatitle').activate(this);" 
   onmouseout="jQuery('#agendatitle').deactivate();" 
   onmousedown="jQuery('#agendatitle').selectItem(this);" logo-colour="#FFF">No
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Whats your question?Not getting properly you want to get the first element or last element?

Comment: My question is how to write an xpath for each of this 2 elements that will distinguish them form one another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Following XPATH to get the element.

1st element

```
  //li[@class='logoSelectOption' and contains(@onmouseover,'worktitle') and contains(.,'No')]
```

2nd element

```
  //li[@class='logoSelectOption' and contains(@onmouseover,'agendatitle') and contains(.,'No')]
```

Or Following CSS selector.

```
li.logoSelectOption[onmouseover*='worktitle']
li.logoSelectOption[onmouseover*='agendatitle']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try these very simple xpath to locate both elements

**For first element:**

```
(//li[@id='N'])[1]
```

**For second element:**

```
(//li[@id='N'])[2]
```